# How to show uidatepicker from uitableviewcell

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

How can I show a `UIDatePicker` from UITableViewCell, and have the `datepicker` have a toolbar at the top that lefts you resign it? Are there any good tutorials on how to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've recently just had to do the exact same thing.

1. Insert a `UITextField` into your `UITableViewCell` (you may need to create a custom `UITableViewCell` depending whether you want it to appear on every dynamic cell of your `UITableView` or on a single static cell).
2. Create properties for a `UIDatePicker`, a `UIToolbar`, and a `UITextField`, then in IB hook up the `UITextField` property to your `UITextField` created in Step 1 (If you're using a custom `UITableViewCell` class, that's where the `UITextField` property would need to go):

   ```
   @property (strong, nonatomic) UIDatePicker * datePicker;
   @property (strong, nonatomic) UIToolbar * datePickerToolbar;
   @property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *textField;

   ...

   @synthesize datePicker, datePickerToolbar, textField;
   ```
3. Setup your `UIDatePicker`, `UIToolbar`, and `UITextField`:

   ```
   - (void)viewDidLoad {
       // Initialise UIDatePicker
       datePicker = [[UIDatePicker alloc] init];
       datePicker.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerModeTime;
       [datePicker addTarget:self action:@selector(datePickerValueChanged:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged]; // method to respond to changes in the picker value

       // Setup UIToolbar for UIDatePicker
       datePickerToolbar = [[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.bounds.size.width, 44)];
       [datePickerToolbar setBarStyle:UIBarStyleBlackTranslucent];    
       UIBarButtonItem *extraSpace = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:nil action:nil];
       UIBarButtonItem *doneButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Done" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleDone target:self action:@selector(dismissPicker:)]; // method to dismiss the picker when the "Done" button is pressed    
       [datePickerToolbar setItems:[[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects: extraSpace, doneButton, nil]];


       // Note: If you're using dynamic cells, the below 2 lines need to be in your cellForRowAtIndexPath method instead.

       // Set UITextfield's inputView as UIDatePicker    
       textField.inputView = datePicker;
       // Set UITextfield's inputAccessoryView as UIToolbar
       textField.inputAccessoryView = datePickerToolbar;
   }
   ```
4. Setup `dismissPicker` method:

   ```
   -(void)dismissPicker:(id)sender{
       [textField resignFirstResponder];
   }
   ```
5. Setup `datePickerValueChanged` method:

   ```
   - (void)datePickerValueChanged:(id)sender{
       NSDate *selectedDate = datePicker.date;

       NSDateFormatter *df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
       [df setDateFormat:@"HH:mm"]; 

       [textField setText:[df stringFromDate:selectedDate]];
   }
   ```

Note: In my code, I needed the interface to display the time, hence the date format set here (`HH:mm`). Because of this, you will also notice that in my `UIDatePicker` initialization code in `viewDidLoad`, I've set its mode to `UIDatePickerModeTime`. For date selections, you may want to set it to `UIDatePickerModeDate`.

Comment: this is great, however could you elaborate on a couple things. First I get this error when I try to resign the datepicker: -[UIBarButtonItem resignFirstResponder]: unrecognized selector  and also, could you explain how I would then set the textfields text to the date the user set. Would it be something like textField.text = ??

Comment: @Auser Oops, please check the edit on my `dismissPicker` code. Also, I've added code for a new method to react to `UIControlEventValueChanged` as well as the code to set it up on the `UIDatePicker`.

Comment: this is so awesome man. Thanks for taking the time to walk me through this. Really appreciate it.

Comment: @Auser No worries, hope this works for you as it did for me! :)

Comment: awesome, I know it will :]

Comment: Great!! Yazid... worked like charm

Answer (score 3):

You could put an invisible UITextField in the UITableViewCell and set the UITextFields inputview to a UIDatePicker. Here us the code:

```
 yourdatePicker = [[UIDatePicker alloc]init];
 yourtextField.inputView = yourdatePicker;
```

Answer (score 0):

I am using ActionSheetPicker[1]. It allows you to show any kind of picker from an action-sheet partly overlapping the current scene. Additionally, you can add buttons (like cancel or "today") and a title to the top of the view.

[1]: Original version by Tim Cinel: https://github.com/TimCinel/ActionSheetPicker
Improvements by Hari Karam Singh: https://github.com/Club15CC/ActionSheetPicker
Fixed deprecations in my fork (I think it spread into the others by now): https://github.com/booiiing/ActionSheetPicker