# How to display date picker and picker view in table cell in iOS?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios7

I have seen this 
       https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/DateCell/Introduction/Intro.html (Date Cell) for my question but this is use Store board in this example and I am not use store board. so how can do this in my view controller.

Comment: Have you searched SO or Google for help ? Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18973573/ios-7-how-to-display-a-date-picker-in-place-in-a-table-view) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17775913/how-to-show-uidatepicker-from-uitableviewcell) first.

Comment: The apple code is horrible. This project displays date picker without storyboard https://github.com/ajaygautam/DateCellWithoutStoryboard

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
// Cell.m

@interface Cell ()

@property (strong, nonatomic) UIPickerView *pickerView;

@end    

@implementation

- (void)initPickerView {
    _pickerView = [[UIPickerView alloc] init];
}

- (void)showPickerView {
    CGRect pickerViewFrame = _pickerView.frame;
    pickerViewFrame.origin.y = self.frame.size.height;
    _pickerView.frame = pickerViewFrame;

    [self addSubview:_pickerView];

    CGRect cellFrame = self.frame;
    cellFrame.size.height += pickerViewFrame.size.height;
    self.frame = cellFrame;
}

- (void)hidePickerView {
    CGRect cellFrame = self.frame;
    cellFrame.size.height -= _pickerView.frame.size.height;
    self.frame = cellFrame;

    [_pickerView removeFromSuperview];
}

@end
```

First of all, initialize picker view with `initPickerView` method in any place before using the view. Then, when you need picker view to appear use `showPickerView`. And use `hidePickerView` to remove it from the cell.